# Send SMS via phone connected with USB

Tags: c#, wpf, mobile, sms

Is there any way to use phone connected with USB to PC for sending sms messages?
Well, I found GsmComm library (http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm), but my device is connected with USB cable, not COM.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-do-i-send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone or http://superuser.com/questions/86076/how-do-i-send-smses-from-my-computer-through-an-android-phone

Answer (score 0):

Try this app on google drive.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smscontrolcenter&hl=en